# Parameter for Websphere MQ queue Messages Size

Tags: ibm-mq

I know that MAXMSGL parameter sets the maximumn message size a quueue can hold.Is there a parameter to set the total size of all the messages the queue can hold.

Comment: MAXMSGL * MAXQDEPTH will give the total size of all messages a queue can hold. Not sure if this is that what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks...what is the maximum all allowed queue depth in websphere?

Answer (score 0):

`MAXDEPTH` is the correct name for maximum queue depth. I have incorrectly mentioned it as `MAXQDEPTH` above. The maximum allowed value is 999999999 on AIX®, HP-UX, z/OS®, Solaris, Linux, and Windows. On IBM® i, the value cannot exceed 640 000.